# Failed to resolve assembly: 'BehaviorsLibrary when using the NuGet package by david.britch

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, nuget

I am trying to use the NuGet package: Behaviors.Forms

I was able to download it and I added this to my page:

```
 xmlns:b="clr-namespace:Behaviors;assembly=BehaviorsLibrary"
```

But I am getting the error:

> Failed to resolve assembly: 'BehaviorsLibrary, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'

I've searched everywhere I can think of to try and find out how to correctly add the assembly but it seems not to be documented.

How can I find the name of the assembly?  When I click on the NuGet package there don't seem to be options for me to learn more about it. Is there a way that I can find this out from properties or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know the NuGet package name and you know the author name. That can easily lead you to the [project site](https://github.com/davidbritch/behaviors) (usually GitHub).

Usually there is [a sample solution](https://github.com/davidbritch/behaviors/tree/master/Sample) you can download and see how it works.

Inside the sample solution you can open [one](https://github.com/davidbritch/behaviors/blob/master/Sample/Behaviors.Sample/AnimationDemoPage.xaml) [of](https://github.com/davidbritch/behaviors/blob/master/Sample/Behaviors.Sample/GotoStateDemoPage.xaml) [the](https://github.com/davidbritch/behaviors/blob/master/Sample/Behaviors.Sample/InvokeCommandDemoPage.xaml) [XAML](https://github.com/davidbritch/behaviors/blob/master/Sample/Behaviors.Sample/InvokeMethodDemoPage.xaml) [pages](https://github.com/davidbritch/behaviors/blob/master/Sample/Behaviors.Sample/SetPropertyDemoPage.xaml) and see how the author references his own creation.